# Как проиграть мелодию из памяти телефона на Android?

Tags: android, delphi

Как при нажатии на кнопку осуществить проигрывание мелодии с заданным путем?Android

Comment: А чо, есть дельфи на андроид? Это не сарказм, мне действительно интересно, вдруг метка дельфи по делу)

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка есть, уже несколько лет, и на iOS есть.

Comment: Уточните вопрос, какая мелодия (где лежит, в каком формате), где и как должна проиграться, версии Делфи и Андроида?

Answer (score 2):

Статейку нашел: [как создать медиаплеер](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Building_a_Basic_Media_Player)

Если вкратце - используйте компонент `TMediaPlayer`

```
MediaPlayer1.FileName := 'file.mp3';
MediaPlayer1.Play;
```

Также пример можно посмотреть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34974562/2546083)

Comment: Пробовал ваш код, однако и на win и android не работает, при чем ошибок никаких нет, просто нажимаю на кнопку и ничего не происходит.

Comment: @Makine а путь к файлу указываете правильный? Скорее всего в этом проблема. Вот ещё инструкция: [FMX.Media.TMediaPlayer или пишем свой mp3-плеер для Android'а #1](http://delphifmandroid.blogspot.com.by/2013/11/fmxmediatmediaplayer-mp3-android.html)